# How to align equal sign

Tags: horizontal-alignment

[image]
I want to make all equal sign align. So I tried many of the solutions in this forum but to no effect. I still couldn't make it work. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
[...]
Where $H\left(\frac{\omega_{0}}{2},\mu\right)$ is the Hamiltonian for isotropic $2-D$ oscillator with frequency $\frac{\omega_{0}}{2}\\
\begin{align}
\left[H\left(\frac{\omega_{0}}{2},\mu\right),L_{z}\right]&=\left[H\left(\frac{\omega_{0}}{2},\mu\right),xp_{y}-yp_{x}\right]\\
\qquad &=\frac{1}{2\mu}\left(\left[p_{x}^2,xp_{y}\right]+\left[p_{y}^2,-yp_{x}\right]\right)+\frac{\mu\omega_{0}^2}{8}\left(\left[x^2,-yp_{x}\right]+\left[y^2,xp_{y}\right]\right)\\
\qquad &=\frac{1}{2\mu}\left[2p_{x}p_{y}(-i\hbar)+2(i\hbar)p_{y}p_{x}\right]+\frac{\mu\omega_{0}^2}{8}\left[2yx(-i\hbar)+2xy(i\hbar)\right]\\
\qquad &=0\textrm{\qquad, }\left([p_{x},p_{y}]=[x,y]=0\right)$\\
\end{align}
[...]
\end{document}
```

I always get this error message:

```
    ! Package amsmath Error: \begin{align} allowed only in paragraph mode.

    See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
    Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
     ...                                              

    l.65 \begin{align}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: In that first line of text, you enter math mode and then go straight into the `align`. You should enter the `align` from outside math mode.

Comment: `\everymath{\displaystyle}` is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that `all` means "all but the final vectors".

The lines, where the code was changed, are marked %here.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
[...]
Where $H\left(\frac{\omega_{0}}{2},\mu\right)$ is the Hamiltonian for isotropic $2-D$ oscillator with frequency $\frac{\omega_{0}}{2}$ %here
\begin{align}
\left[H\left(\frac{\omega_{0}}{2},\mu\right),L_{z}\right]&=\left[H\left(\frac{\omega_{0}}{2},\mu\right),xp_{y}-yp_{x}\right]\\
\qquad &=\frac{1}{2\mu}\left(\left[p_{x}^2,xp_{y}\right]+\left[p_{y}^2,-yp_{x}\right]\right)+\frac{\mu\omega_{0}^2}{8}\left(\left[x^2,-yp_{x}\right]+\left[y^2,xp_{y}\right]\right)\\
\qquad &=\frac{1}{2\mu}\left[2p_{x}p_{y}(-i\hbar)+2(i\hbar)p_{y}p_{x}\right]+\frac{\mu\omega_{0}^2}{8}\left[2yx(-i\hbar)+2xy(i\hbar)\right]\\
\qquad &=0\textrm{\qquad, }\left([p_{x},p_{y}]=[x,y]=0\right) %here
\end{align}
[...]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additionally, please observe that `\\` before an equation-like environment is completely unneeded.

Comment: Couldn't have done it without your help.

Comment: Not only ``\\`` is unneeded, it may also do harm like adding a blank line.

Answer (score 4):

Przemysław Scherwentke has [answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204720/15874) your question but there are some improvement to be done to the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setlength\parindent{4em}

\begin{document}

[\dots]
where $H{\mkern -5mu}\left(\frac{\omega_{0}}{2}, \mu\right){\mkern -5mu}$ is the Hamiltonian for isotropic $\mathrm{2D}$ oscillator with frequency $\frac{\omega_{0}}{2}$;
\begin{align}
  \left[H{\mkern -5mu}\left(\frac{\omega_{0}}{2}, \mu\right){\mkern -5mu}, L_{z}\right]
  &= \left[H{\mkern -5mu}\left(\frac{\omega_{0}}{2}, \mu\right){\mkern -5mu}, xp_{y} - yp_{x}\right]\\
  &= \frac{1}{2\mu}{\mkern -3mu}\left(\left[p_{x}^{2}, xp_{y}\right] + \left[p_{y}^{2}, -yp_{x}\right]\right){\mkern -3mu} + \frac{\mu\omega_{0}^{2}}{8}{\mkern -3mu}\left(\left[x^{2}, -yp_{x}\right] + \left[y^{2}, xp_{y}\right]\right){\mkern -3mu}\\
  &= \frac{1}{2\mu}[2p_{x}p_{y}(-i\hbar) + 2(i\hbar)p_{y}p_{x}] + \frac{\mu\omega_{0}^{2}}{8}[2yx(-i\hbar) + 2xy(i\hbar)]\\
  &= 0,\qquad ([p_{x}, p_{y}] = [x, y] = 0)
\end{align}
[\dots]

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

**Update**

Incorporating Mico's suggestion gives the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setlength\parindent{4em}

\begin{document}

[\dots]
where $H\mleft(\frac{\omega_{0}}{2}, \mu\mright)$ is the Hamiltonian for isotropic $\mathrm{2D}$ oscillator with frequency $\frac{\omega_{0}}{2}$;
\begin{align}
  \left[H\mleft(\frac{\omega_{0}}{2}, \mu\mright), L_{z}\right]
  &= \mleft[H\mleft(\frac{\omega_{0}}{2}, \mu\mright), xp_{y} - yp_{x}\mright]\\
  &= \frac{1}{2\mu}\mleft(\mleft[p_{x}^{2}, xp_{y}\mright] + \mleft[p_{y}^{2}, -yp_{x}\mright]\right) + \frac{\mu\omega_{0}^{2}}{8}\left(\mleft[x^{2}, -yp_{x}\mright] + \mleft[y^{2}, xp_{y}\mright]\mright)\\
  &= \frac{1}{2\mu}[2p_{x}p_{y}(-i\hbar) + 2(i\hbar)p_{y}p_{x}] + \frac{\mu\omega_{0}^2}{8}[2yx(-i\hbar) + 2xy(i\hbar)]\\
  &= 0,\qquad ([p_{x}, p_{y}] = [x, y] = 0)
\end{align}
[\dots]

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Here, the [`mleftright`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mleftright) package is added to remove the `{\mkern -<x>mu}` constructions.

Comment: To get rid of the undesirable horizontal whitespace inserted by all those `\left` and `\right` directives, one could load the `mleftright` package and issue the instruction `\mleftright` in the preamble. That way, the `\mkern -5mu` statements are no longer needed.